# Is every power series infinitely differentiable everywhere?

Tags: power-series

I have found various sources on the internet that say that power series are infinitely differentiable on their interval of convergence:

[Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Differentiation_and_integration)

> Once a function $f(x)$ is given as a power series as above, **it is differentiable on the interior of the domain of convergence**.

[Northwestern University:](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~scanez/courses/320/notes/analytic-functions.pdf)

> [...] power series are (infinitely) differentiable **on their intervals of convergence** [...]

---

But isn't every power series (infinitely) differentiable everywhere?

After all, a power series is *just* an infinite polynomial and a polynomial of degree $n$ is differentiable $n+1$ times. [Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3189775)

Doesn't this imply, that a polynomial of "degree $\infty$" is differentiable $\infty$ times?

Comment: "a power series is just an infinite polynomial". Following that logic, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 1$ is just a number.

Comment: It‘s rather about where the power series is even well-defined.

Comment: You are right that a **formal** power series is just an infinite degree polynomial. This is a purely algebraic viewpoint that is sometimes useful; see for example the book "Generatingfunctionology", by Herbert Wilf. However, the analytic aspects of the manipulation of power series depend on its convergence properties; differentiability is one such aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this was an issue of language and my understanding of what it means for a derivative to *exist*.

It is of course possible to "derive" (e.g. blindly following the rules of differentiation) term-by-term like this:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-c)^n = a_0 + a_1(x-c) + a_2(x-c)^2 + a_3(x-c)^3 + ...
$$
$$
f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n(x-c)^{n-1} = a_1 + 2a_2(x-c) + 3a_3(x-c)^2 + ...
$$

However, an infinite sum **only exists, if it converges!**
Therefore, if the infinite sum does not converge (which it might, depending on $x$), it does not exist, and therefore the derivative itself does not exist for those values of $x$.

The radius of convergence of the power series and its derivatives is the same: [Source 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1914362), [Source 2](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Radius_of_Convergence_of_Derivative_of_Complex_Power_Series).

---

**Edit**
I would like to highlight this statement by Kavi Rama Murthy from the comments, because it complements this answer:

> [The terms of the derived series] make sense for any $x$ but the infinite sum makes sense only within the circle of convergence.

Comment: To be more explicit let me make the following statements: The series $\sum n a_n (x-c)^{n-1}$ can be called the 'derived series'. Its terms make sense for any $x$ but the infinite sum makes sense only within the circle of convergence. And in this circle $f'(x)$ exists and it is given by the infinite sum.

Comment: See also- differentiation of formal power series

Answer (score 6):

There is lot of difference between polynomials and power series.

You  cannot define $\sum z^{n}$ for $|z| >1$. So there is no question of differentiability of this on $\{z: |z| >1\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My issue was that I did not understand what it means for a derivative to _exist_. Can you take a look at my own answer and check that my new understanding is correct?